# Xcode : failed to link application

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation

I have a new error happening when compiling my app with XCode (I think it happens in the linking process), here is the cryptic error message :

`ld: file not found: /Users/stanislas.heili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXX-fauperpdaeyhczddatnqzxmedtxd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XXXXX.build/Debug Live-iphoneos/XXXXX.build/Objects-normal/arm64/XXXXXDistribution.o`

There are two strange things in this error :

- It happens only for me (the other developers that work on the project do not face this issue)
- I can archive with success but can not debug on device

I tried unsuccessfully to :

- go back a few commits to one where I am sure it used to work a week ago
- clear XCode derived data
- reset cache of the package manager
- uninstall and reinstall XCode
- delete the code and clone again

Do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

goto Xcode --> product ->scheme -> edit scheme -> check that build Configuration (Debug or Release)

you are debug - change that Debug configuration.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am in Debug already, what should I change ?

Comment: hi pls check that configuration mode debug or no

Comment: next uninstall development certificate again install that certificate file(that development certificate must be added device UDID)